# Unit Test Organization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit-2.5

I'm using Nunit for unit testing, and added another project called "Unit Testing" to my current solution.  I referenced Nunit, and changed the Namespace to the same namespace used in the main project.

I can't seem to figure out how to get access to all the classes, files, etc in the main project. Is there something I have to do to link two projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add a project reference to your main project?  Right click on your Unit Test project --> add reference --> project --> select your Main Project and add it

Answer (score 0):

In your "Unit Testing" project, you just need to add a reference to the main project you want to test, just like you added the reference to NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the project like you would if you were linking any project that were held in the same Solution file.